Что дальше после авторизации через oauth2?
Создаю web приложение, где необходимо распределение прав доступа.
Для начала нужно юзеру же пройти идентификацию, аутентификацию и авторизацию, если все ок - провайдер, например, google oauth2 дает токены, id, email, username и.т.д. и на этом авторизация завершена.
А что дальше делать с этими данными? Самое полезное это id чтобы знать кто ты есть, а токены по факту чтоб только посылать запросы к google. Как следить за тем, что доступ у юзера все еще имеется, регулярно посылать запросы? К тому же может быть такое, что юзер в аккаунте google отзовет доступ к приложению, как приложение должно об этом узнать, опять же регулярно опрашивать?
То есть суть моего вопроса, что дальше после авторизации, ведь этот этап ток дает доступ, а не следит за ним?

access token имеет малый срок действия. Скажем пять минут. Если админ отберёт у пользователя доступы, через пять минут его токены истекут, а новых ему не дадут.

@StanislavVolodarskiy но стороннее приложение не узнает, что токен истёк, пока не зафлудит гyгл запросами с этим токеном (ну или попытаться декодировать срок действия из токена, если он там есть, но есть ли гарантии, что это не перестанет работать в будущем?)

@andreymal, access token проверяется без обращения к серверам. Клиент передаёт серверу токен, который трудно подделать, сервер проверяет его автономно и возвращает ответ или сигнал "токен устарел". Если токен устарел, клиент обращается к сервису, который выписывает новый коротко живущий access token. То есть, вы можете делать сотни запросов в минуту, а обращение к авторизации будет проходить только раз в пять минут.

@andreymal, и даже это обращение раз в пять минут можно организовать без задержки. Для этого новый access token запрашивается за тридцать секунд до истечения предыдущего.

@andreymal, https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token. Схема из access и refresh токенов прикольная. Я бы никогда не подумал, что защита данных может быть интересной, но этот кусок устроен прямо таки красиво.

@StanislavVolodarskiy это если гарантируется использование JSON Web Token, а гарантируется ли оно?

@andreymal, oauth2 использует ту же схему. JWT я привёл только как иллюстрацию принципа.
